# Mark the replacement of the content

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to find “Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci” in the article, replacing him with “Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA” and highlighting it as green.
 I wrote the following code. It **only marked** “Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci.“ As green and **did not mark** USA as green.                                                                           how can I mark **whole** “Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA” as green?

```
 Sub add_usa()
    selection.find.clearforamtting
        With selection.Find
            .Text = "Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. "
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Forward = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            Do
                .Execute
                If .Found And selection.Range.Next(wdCharacter, 1) <> "U" Then
                    selection.Range.InsertAfter "USA "
                    selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
                End If
                If Not .Found Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the lines about modifying the range inside a With block:

```
With Selection.Range
  .InsertAfter "USA "
  .HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
End With
```

(Tested in Word 2010)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Find and Replace:-

```
Sub Add_USA()

    Const ExistingText As String = "Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci."
    Const NewText As String = "Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA"

    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ExistingText
        .Replacement.Text = NewText
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

End Sub
```